# Why does mb_decode_numericentity() produce a exit(136)?

Tags: php

I don't understand why this code produce a "Floating point exception" in a unit test and a exit(136) in a minimal example?

```
mb_decode_numericentity(
    '&#x00000072;',
    [0x80, 0xfffff, 0, 0xfffff, 0],
    'UTF-8'
);
```

minimal example: https://3v4l.org/XUXXu

unit-test: https://travis-ci.org/voku/anti-xss/jobs/443443602#L4492